# What functions have f(x) = f'(x)

Tags: calculus

I am aware of two distinct functions that are equal to their derivatives.

- $f(x) = 0$
- $f(x) = e^x$

Are there any others?
Including functions that do not have closed form representations.

Comment: Technically, you have $f(x)=ae^x$ is the general solution here, and so both you have listed are for values $a=0,1$.

Comment: You can argue this with power series.

Comment: If it has a power series.